# Using react-select with an array of plain strings as options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to use the react-select widget and pass a simple array of strings to it as the list of options instead of the default `{value, label}` objects. I have already successfully configured react-select to use objects with different properties than the default, so I assumed that configuring it for plain strings would simply work. But it doesn't, no matter which item I select the visible selection in the widget remains always empty.

I'm using react-select 4.3.1, and the following is a simplified example that exhibits the behaviour I've seen:

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

const optionsStringsOnly = ["Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Vanilla"];

const MyComponent = () => <Select options={options} />;

const MyComponent2 = () => (
  <Select
    options={optionsStringsOnly}
    getOptionLabel={(x) => x}
    getOptionValue={(x) => x}
  />
);
```

The `MyComponent` version is from the react-select examples, and works as expected. The `Mycomponent2` version does not work, and I don't understand why. I have successfully used the getOptionLabel and getOptionValue props to use objects with a different shape, but for plain strings this simply does not work.

I know there are other questions about using plain strings with react-select, but those assume that simply converting the options to `{value,label}` objects before passing them to react-select is acceptable. I want to avoid that as that would require reconverting the values later, which would be really annoying in my case. I want to pass in plain strings and get plain strings out of the react-select widget again.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I use plain strings as options with react-select?

Comment: What's the error message here?

Comment: @NearHuscarl there is no error message, it simply does not show the selected option in the widget. So the text field always remains empty even after I select one of the options from the dropdown.

Comment: When you say "reconverting the values later", what exactly do you mean? React-Select does require that options be as objects, so just trying to figure out why doing `options.map(it => ({value: it, label: it})` creates a problem for you? What is the key issue to using that pattern?

Comment: @Steve-Cutter-Blades The output I need from the form are plain strings, if I put in objects I also get objects back out of the form. I'd really like to avoid special handling for this in my submit function, nothing else in the forms needs this. It looks a bit like react-select isn't designed for this, and I'll need to work around it, but my first impression was that everything should go through the two functions I pass as props, so it should not matter what I put in there as long as I put the conversion functions in as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most people use state for `value`, in conjunction with an `onChange` handler for controlling it. By your comments, it appears that you are just looking for a form field with the value in it for a typical form POST scenario, as opposed to handling a composed JS object.

If you provide the mapping, and a `name` prop, you may get exactly what you need. By doing this:

```js
const MyComponent2 = () => {
  const options = optionsStringsOnly.map(it => ({value: it, label:it}));
  return <Select name="foo_select" options={options} />;
};
```

When a selection is made, that `value` is then applied to the hidden form field with the `name` supplied. If you were to inspect the source in the browser you would see:

```html
<input name="foo_select" type="hidden" value="Chocolate">
```

The `name` prop is critical here, as that's what tells React-Select to include the hidden field in the first place.

The downside to doing it this way is that you have no way of programmatically controlling your field value. You could set the value of the hidden field, but it would not automatically update the display.